# How is the integration response selected when there are multiple matching error regexes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

When you define an integration response in AWS API Gateway, you have to provide a regex pattern that will be tested against the response from the backend. How does API Gateway choose the integration response to use when there are multiple integration responses with matching patterns?

For instance, if I have an integration response with the pattern "INVALID_DATA", and another one with the pattern "INVALID_.+", which one will be used if the response from the backend is "INVALID_DATA"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway will pick the first regex pattern matches, so the order cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to provide a default error integration response, that would match any errorMessage value that does not match any other pattern?